# I can't connect to other machines within the same network

Tags: networking, apache2

I'm developing a portal and the main aim for this portal is for all my colleagues (whose machines are connected to the same network) to access the portal.

I have tried to reinstall my apache server and it still gives me the same error.
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

I have limited knowledge when it comes to networks and any help will be really great.

[This is the supposed output when another machine typed the ip address of my machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXcEL.png)

I installed virtualbox and tried to test the problem using that. When I open the chrome and firefox in virtualbox I get these messages:

```
Firefox:

Unable to connect

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at xxx.xxx.xx.240.

The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

```
Chrome:

This site can't be reached
xxx.xxx.xx.240 is unreachable
ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
```

I even tried to acess my portal using a machine that has windows as its os it it gives me this error:

```
Chrome on windows:

This site can't be reached
xxx.xxx.xx.240 took too long to respond
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

This is the most recent error logs in my apache

```
[Wed Jun 12 07:35:05.832875 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1967] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jun 12 07:35:05.832891 2019] [core:notice] [pid 1967] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Jun 12 15:20:14.048524 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1967] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Jun 12 15:31:50.238257 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2707] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jun 12 15:31:50.280681 2019] [core:notice] [pid 2707] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: no information, no question?

Comment: You've given statements, but I too can't find an question, just reference to unspecified error.  For most help it should be clear to us, exact command used plus error message.

Comment: I just edited my question sorry about that

Comment: Does it works with the ip address instead of the host name? - Can you ping the ip address of the server from the client? And with the host name? - If no to the previous question, are they on the same network (cf. addresses and mask) and physically reachable (e.g connected to the same router, for example) - Please check also that your VM can be reached from "outside", in the virtual box parameters (don't remember how, but that's something related to the networking setup on Virtual box in itself. Do you have any firewall on the server?

Comment: A:I get the same errors unfortunately
A:Yes I can ping my machine through another machine. I can even ping my machine through my virtualbox
A:Yes they are not the same network which is .60 (all of our machines here in the office are connected to the same network)
A:I don't know if this is the right answer but I tried to ping my VM using a machine used by may colleague and it works
A:I don't really have an idea if a firewall exists in our server. but I can access our old portal (w/c is also connected in the same network) without any fuss

Comment: I tried to answer all of your questions. maybe its the configuration of my apache but I don't have any idea how to configure it without wrecking my connections (I've wrecked my apache once trying to figure out this problem)

Comment: @FrancisKane It would be a good idea to check the apache logs

Comment: @MichaelHooreman I just edited my question and posted the most recent error log but I don't know what to make of it. I don't have much knowledge when it comes to networks

Comment: @FrancisKane it seems that nothing happened in the apache error logs, except a restart of the dameon.
Can you try telnet 127.0.0.1 {yourhttpport} (e.g. 127.0.0.1 80)? Can you also {yourip} {yourhttpport}? In both cases, hit twice [Enter], you sould receive most probably a HTTP 400 Bad Request if it works.

Comment: @MichaelHooreman this is just weird but i just reinstalled my ssh and sshd and suddenly any machine now here in the office has access to my portal

Comment: @MichaelHooreman this is just weird I came into office today and when e booted up my pc the errors returned. but when I tried your suggestion this are the results: with the telnet 127.0.0.1 `Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
I also got the HTTP 400 Bad request
`
I also tried my ip in the telnet and same result

Comment: @FrancisKeane And what is the result of tje telnet from another computer of your.network to the server?

Comment: @MichaelHooreman `Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host`
there is a time when I can access my portal in another computer. but when I restart my pc (the server). I can't access again the portal in another pc.

Comment: @FrancisKane Please check with your network administrator. It's most probably about the name resolution or IP address change. A server has usually a fixed IP address ... or the DNS must know in "real time" what the IP address is. But there might be other reasons.